# How to find the solution of following differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given with the differential equation $$y''+\left(\frac{A}{z}-Bz+C\right)y'+\left(\frac{D}{z}-E\right)y = \frac{G}{z}$$ where $y= y(z)$ and $A, B, C, D, E$ are constants.

I know two methods (Changing the dependent variable and changing the independent variable) for solving the problem. But unable to find the solution.

Is there  any other method which can be applied to this problem? Please help me.

Comment: the solution containes the Whitteker function

Comment: I've added the first derivative of y. Please check  that is correct.

Comment: @PM. Sorry i can't understand what do you mean?

Comment: @MittalG Click on the 'edited Apr 17' below your question and above 'PM.' and you can see side-by-side your question before and after my edit. I added a $y'$ to your equation in the 2nd term, otherwise the 2nd term does not depend on $y$ in any way.